# Convert Zulu timestamp to seconds since epoch and compare it with current time in bash script Mac

Tags: linux, bash, macos, timestamp, epoch

I have below timestamp, which I need to change to seconds since epoch in a bash script, Mac OS and compare with current system time.

2021-09-21T06:27:15Z

Current System Time is in IST format. i.e Tue Sep 21 12:20:42 IST 2021

Please suggest a better way to achieve it.

Answer (score 2):

This should give you what you want:

```
#!/bin/bash

date="2021-09-21T06:27:15Z"

epoch=$(date -d "${date}" +%s)
```

Comment: for macOS use: epoch=$(date -j -u -f %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ "${date}" +%s)